# Safe JavasScript that calls PHP script that calls external web service

Tags: php, javascript, security, jquery

I have a PHP page that needs to make a call to a external web service. This Web service call takes a bunch of sensitive data from a html form on the PHP page, e.g. SSN, and returns info related to that person.

The problem is that the web service call should be made as soon as the customer fills in the SSN field and the field loses focus, so the page cannot be reloaded in any way. I was thinking about using jQuery to make a call to the web service, but AJAX unfortunately requires that you are on the same domain as the requested resource. So I'm thinking about creating an local PHP page that makes the call to the web service and then use JQuery to call this new page.

Questions:

1. How do I use JQuery to call the local PHP script that makes the call to the web service?
2. Because the JQuery code will take sensitive data from a html form and send it to the PHP script, how can I encrypt the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call your PHP file:

```
var url = "http://localhost/data.php";
var params = {
  "SSN" : theSSN
};
$.get(url, params, function (){
  // Do whatever you need here, once the data arrives.
});
```

To call the external webservice from PHP, I'd suggest using [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

To encrypt, I'd suggest using the HTTPS protocol instead of encrypting manually from JavaScript.

Comment: In the PHP script, how do I return data so that it is received by the jquery call? I've tried echo and return, but doesn't work.

Comment: A nice way to do it is to echo some JSON data. But you'll need to use $.getJSON instead of $.get. Look at the json_encode PHP function; it will convert your PHP data into JS format for further reading in JS world. That's what I do almost always :)

Answer (score 1):

1) $.get("myscript.php", function(response) { alert(response) });

2) I wouldn't encrypt using jQuery, it would be slow and easy to decrypt. Enabling SSL on the server would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

1: Ajax request example:

```
$.ajax(
{
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.php",
       success: function (msg) { //does something }
});
```

More details [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

2: php XOR is a pretty good encryption algorithm, I use it myself for a project with sensitive data. you can find the function [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/xor-encryption.htm).

Enjoy! :)

Comment: XOR encrypt would require the passkey to be client-side as well, so it's not that secure. Stronger encryption methods are asymmetric.

Comment: Some data can be encrypted while first page(the one with the form) executes (if the data is not wrote by the user)

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help you in particular, but some webservices support something called JSONP, which adds a callback name to a normal JSON request.

However, chances are you will need to make some sort of local proxy, as not many JSONP services exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is enabling SSL on your domain, and doing the xmlHTTPRequest to the https of the remote service